# How to call a method in an If-statement inside an If-statement?

Tags: java, towers-of-hanoi

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class test {
  public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Enter disc to move: ");
    int disc=in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter destination: ");
    char dest=in.next().charAt(0);

    if ((disc==1)&&((dest=='B')||(dest=='b'))){
      AAB(disc,dest);
      {
        printM(disc, dest);
        {
          if ((disc==2)&&((dest=='C')||(dest=='c')))
            ACB(disc, dest);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void AAB(int disc, char dest){
        System.out.println("A: 32");
        System.out.println("B: 1");
        System.out.println("C: ");
        System.out.println(" ");
  }
  public static void ACB(int disc, char dest){
        System.out.println("A: 3");
        System.out.println("B: 1");
        System.out.println("C: 2");
        System.out.println(" ");}
  }
}
```

And my output looks like:

```
Enter disc to move: 1
Enter destination: b
A: 32
B: 1
C: 

Enter disc to move: 2
Enter destination: c
```

Now, my problem is when I enter `2` as my disk and `c` as my destination, it doesn't print my output. I made a method for that condition, which is the `ACB`. 
Can someone help me with my syntax?

I am using these codes for my assignment (tower of hanoi)

Answer (score 2):

The code in your nested `if` statement will never be reached, whether `disc` is equal to **1** or **2**. Change

```
if ((disc==1)&&((dest=='B')||(dest=='b'))){
    AAB(disc,dest);
    {
    printM(disc, dest);
       {
        if ((disc==2)&&((dest=='C')||(dest=='c')))
            ACB(disc, dest);
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
if ((disc==1)&&((dest=='B')||(dest=='b'))){
    AAB(disc,dest);

    printM(disc, dest);
}
else if ((disc==2)&&((dest=='C')||(dest=='c')))
    ACB(disc, dest);
}
```